# C++ Inherit Librairy Dependencies

Tags: c++, inheritance, dependencies, lib

I have following problem:
I have library with some additional dependencies e.g. glfw. Now I want to use this library in an other project. But then I get errors that it can't find the header glfw.h. I can fix this by adding glfw to the dependencies.
Is there a way that I don't have to do this?

Comment: "I have library with some additional dependencies"* - the problem isn't the dependencies so much as the public interface to *your* library exposes those dependencies to your library consumer. If you don't want that you need to move all glfw source-level dependencies out of your publicly exposed interface and use it strictly internal to your lib. And in case it wasn't already obvious, making that decision is generally much *much* easier when designing your lib rather than after it's already implemented. You may have some work cut out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Aslong as no file I include uses glfw it works! But if I can only include the librairy files in the cpp files that will be linked it will be really hard to work with. You said something about making interfaces internal. But what does this mean and how can I make that?

Comment: One method is called the pimpl pattern (pointer to implementation). As I said, it's much easier to design like this from the start rather than the finish. You're going to have to think about it for awhile and possibly change how you craft your implementation vs exposed API(s).

Comment: That you! It works. I didn't start the project yet so I don't have to redesign my whole librairy.